# I have just installed Ubuntu 14.02 and I didnt make any partitoin of my HDD (500GB) then. I tried now by Gparted but no luck. I want 3 partition

Tags: partitioning, gparted

[Gparted Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qghEi.png)

[Unable to resize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5A9f.png)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to run a live USB/CD and resize partitions with that, because the root file system cannot be unmounted.

Comment: I have bootable pan drive. Should i select "Something Else " option ?

Comment: If you don't have a live pen drive at hand, you can use your current system to download and prepare one.

Comment: could u plz navigate me.. I wud appreciate ur help Ralph

Comment: If it's a "normal" ubunutu installation drive, you should choose the "try without installing option". This will run it on the pen drive, and it will show you the other drive, which is the one you want to partition. It has gparted,  so just run that, make sure you select the drive, then modify the partition. OR, maybe just re-run the whole installation, then select the "something else" option while re-installing. Reinstalling will do away with everything of the old installation, so be sure you want that before going this path.